# Multiple entries with same patient id: how to make it one entry

Tags: r

I have multiple entries in my data from same patient ID, I wanted to make it as one entry. What are my possible options? Here is the data -

```html
PtID    WorryHighBGNow
40  5
40  1
40  2
70  3
101 4
263 2
263 5
263 3
143 4
245 4
137 3
219 2
219 3
219 4
3   3
264 3
264 3
98  1
200 3
105 3
111 4
149 3
```

I want to create a visualization like below out of this data, where on y axis I want to see columns of my table and on X I want to se ranking 1,2,3,4,5

[image: picture of visualization]

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. One way would be `aggregate(WorryHighBGNow~PtID, df, toString)` Will that work?

Comment: column number two has rating (1 to 5) on what patient thinks.  I just edited my question with a visualization I want to create out of it.  
My end goal is to find the percentage of people who either answered 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

If x is your data frame you can try this

```
                      d <- setDT(x)[, list(WorryHighBGNow = paste(WorryHighBGNow, collapse = ', ')),by = c('PtID')]
```

It will give result like

```
                     PtID   WorryHighBGNow
                     40     5,1,2
                     70     3
                     101    4
                     263    2,5,3
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure that is what you need. I've just tried to mimic [visualization you linked to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9sWg.png), as close as it possible.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate_all(factor) %>%
  count(WorryHighBGNow, ) %>%
  mutate(percentage = round(n / sum(n) * 100, 1)) %>%
  mutate(WorryHighBGNow =  reorder(WorryHighBGNow, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x    = WorryHighBGNow, y     = percentage, 
             fill = WorryHighBGNow, label = paste(percentage, '%'))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(hjust = -.1, fontface = 'bold') +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', breaks = 1:5) +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(y = 50) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image: scores baplot]

*Data*:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    PtID = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 70L, 101L, 263L, 263L, 263L, 143L, 245L, 137L, 219L, 
             219L, 219L, 3L, 264L, 264L, 98L, 200L, 105L, 111L, 149L), 
    WorryHighBGNow = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                       3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L)
    ), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. This works for me.

Comment: One question, where did you call the csv file in code ?

Comment: I didn't. I copypasted your data like this: ` dat <- read.table(text = "<copy from your question>", header = TRUE)` But if your data are in current directory, and named as lets say **mydata.csv** you can read the file this way `dat <- read.csv("mydata.csv")`.